# How do I trigger build only on PR, and not after merge, on Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

This is a question raised for the [`pyjanitor` project](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor/).

I have build pipelines that are split into jobs, and the jobs are designed to run in parallel. However, I noticed that the builds are triggered even after merging PRs. Hence, my question is kind of two-fold:

1. Is it possible to trigger build such that we only check PRs?
2. Is it even good practice to just check PRs, or is there a rationale for building after merge (and also running all the tests) that I might be missing?

Update:

I believe that this question should be distinct from [the suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891085/force-developer-to-run-unit-test-project-before-pr-is-raised-in-azure-devops) because the question I have is how to **disable** build **after** PR is merged, rather than forcing a build before PR is made.

Looking through the suggested duplicate, I did not find anything about how to configure my Pipeline YAML to disable build after PR merge. The suggested "branch policies" thing also does not show up on my Pipelines dashboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force developer to run unit test project before PR is Raised in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891085/force-developer-to-run-unit-test-project-before-pr-is-raised-in-azure-devops)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to disable build after merge - disable commit trigger.

yaml:

```
trigger: none
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do we do that in the YAML config?